# AWS SES pass data between lambda actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

i have setup 2 Lambda actions, within and SES Ruleset and i'm looking for a way to pass data between the 2 lambda.

Scenario :

- User sends an email to example.com
- SES triggers the first Lambda action in the ruleset on receiving the email
- SES triggers the second Lambda action in the ruleset, with the returned data from the first action

is this possible, or is there another best practice to do so ?

Thank you

Comment: You could simply trigger the second lambda within the first one. I'm wondering what the use case would be where you wouldn't just put all the functionality within the same lambda.

Comment: @TimKlein thanks, but i want to stay in a micro-services architecture and avoid having to invoke lambdas inside other lambda

Answer (score 1):

That is the reason AWS created a service called Step Functions.

You can make a parallel or sequential call between lambda's and pass data between them.

Checkout the documentation  [Step Functions Getting Started](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/getting-started.html)

Comment: Thanks, i saw this solution too, but for a question of cost efficiency, we will invoke the lambda using AWS SDK